# RecyclerView cannot get corrrect position to perform the task when user select option from contextmenu

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, contextmenu

My app cannot get the right position to perform the task that user choose from ContextMenu.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<foodmodel> result;
private foodadapter adapter;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Food");

    result = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.food_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    lim.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);


    adapter = new foodadapter(result);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateList();
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case 0:
            removeFood(item.getItemId());
            break;

        case 1:
            changeFood(item.getItemId());
            break;

    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


private void updateList()
{
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(foodmodel.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            foodmodel food = dataSnapshot.getValue(foodmodel.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(food);

            result.set(index,food);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            foodmodel food = dataSnapshot.getValue(foodmodel.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(food);

            result.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private int getItemIndex(foodmodel food){
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size();i++)
    {
        if (result.get(i).key.equals(food.key))
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return index;
}


private void removeFood(int pos){
    foodmodel food = result.get(pos);
    String key = food.getKey();
    food.u_time="remove";

    Map<String,Object> foodValue = food.toMap();
    Map<String,Object> newFood = new HashMap<>();

    newFood.put(key,foodValue);

    ref.updateChildren(newFood);
}

private void changeFood(int pos){
    foodmodel food = result.get(pos);
    food.u_time="change";

    Map<String,Object> foodValue = food.toMap();
    Map<String,Object> newFood = new HashMap<>();

    newFood.put(food.key,foodValue);

    ref.updateChildren(newFood);
}

}
```

**foodadapter.java**

```
public class foodadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<foodadapter.foodviewholder> {

private List<foodmodel>list;
public foodadapter(List<foodmodel> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public foodviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    return new foodviewholder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(foodviewholder holder, int position) {
    foodmodel food = list.get(position);

    holder.txtname.setText(food.u_food);
    holder.txtdate.setText(food.u_date);
    holder.txttime.setText(food.u_time);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class foodviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    TextView txtname,txtdate,txttime;
    Button btn;

    public foodviewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_food);
        txtdate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
        txttime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        btn = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btntest);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Change");
    }
}
}
```

**foomodel.java**

```
public class foodmodel {

String u_food,u_date,u_time,key;

public foodmodel(){}

public foodmodel(String  u_food,String u_date,String u_time, String key) {
    this.u_food = u_food;
    this.u_date = u_date;
    this.u_time = u_time;
    this.key = key;
}

public Map<String,Object> toMap(){
    HashMap<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("u_food",u_food);
    result.put("u_time",u_time);
    result.put("u_date",u_date);
    result.put("key",key);

    return  result;
}

public String getU_food() {
    return u_food;
}

public void setU_food(String u_food) {
    this.u_food = u_food;
}

public String getU_date() {
    return u_date;
}

public void setU_date(String u_date) {
    this.u_date = u_date;
}

public String getU_time() {
    return u_time;
}

public void setU_time(String u_time) {
    this.u_time = u_time;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
}
```

The flow of the app supposed like

1. display recyclerview that retrieve from Firebases
2. user choose the item from the list
3. contextmenu pop up
4. user choose delete or change
5. if delete, then the u_time of food becomes "remove"
6. if change, then the u_time of food becomes "change"

the step from 1-4 works fine. but after that the app cannot get position to perform task correctly.

For example, if user choose "delete" on third item, but the first item will be changed. After that, user choose "change" on forth item, the second item changed. Is there any problem of my code?

Comment: so means I have to use list not recyclerview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code like :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<foodmodel> result;
private foodadapter adapter;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Food");

    result = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.food_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    lim.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);


    adapter = new foodadapter(result);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateList();
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case 0:
            if(adapter.curPos>-1){
             removeFood(adapter.curPos);
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if(adapter.curPos>-1){
             changeFood(adapter.curPos);
            }
            break;

    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


private void updateList()
{
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(foodmodel.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            foodmodel food = dataSnapshot.getValue(foodmodel.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(food);

            result.set(index,food);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            foodmodel food = dataSnapshot.getValue(foodmodel.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(food);

            result.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private int getItemIndex(foodmodel food){
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size();i++)
    {
        if (result.get(i).key.equals(food.key))
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return index;
}


private void removeFood(int pos){
    foodmodel food = result.get(pos);
    String key = food.getKey();
    food.u_time="remove";

    Map<String,Object> foodValue = food.toMap();
    Map<String,Object> newFood = new HashMap<>();

    newFood.put(key,foodValue);

    ref.updateChildren(newFood);
}

private void changeFood(int pos){
    foodmodel food = result.get(pos);
    food.u_time="change";

    Map<String,Object> foodValue = food.toMap();
    Map<String,Object> newFood = new HashMap<>();

    newFood.put(food.key,foodValue);

    ref.updateChildren(newFood);
}

}
```

**foodadapter.java**

```
public class foodadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<foodadapter.foodviewholder> {

private List<foodmodel>list;
public int curPos=-1;
public foodadapter(List<foodmodel> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public foodviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    return new foodviewholder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(foodviewholder holder, int position) {
    foodmodel food = list.get(position);

    holder.txtname.setText(food.u_food);
    holder.txtdate.setText(food.u_date);
    holder.txttime.setText(food.u_time);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class foodviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    TextView txtname,txtdate,txttime;
    Button btn;

    public foodviewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_food);
        txtdate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
        txttime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        btn = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btntest);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         curPos=getAdapterPosition();
                    }});
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Change");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: there is no any response when I click the option from ContextMenu.. it is because the curPos still -1?

Comment: I think so, do one thing,try to put this `curPos=getAdapterPosition();` inside `@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Change");
    }`

Also debug once inside the click listener in adapter.

Comment: it works for first three item. if I click forth item, the app will crash and no changes with my firebase. if I click fifth item, the app will crash but the data will change.  @Koustuv Ganguly

Comment: Change  `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` this to ` `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);`

Comment: is still the same, I found that many error display in logcat when I click forth item and fifth item.

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: all works fine! I think is my database's problem , because I delete all the data and insert all again. Everythings works fine without any crash after add the curPos into onCreateContextMenu(), thank you so much!